# Salvar em Multiplas Tabelas Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Sou novo no PHP e Zend Framework 2, estou repassando um projeto escrito em C# ASP.NET para PHP utilizando o Zend e me deparei com o seguinte problema.

Tenho 2 tabelas: usuário e logradouro.

Na tabela de usuário tenho: id, nome, email, senha.

Na tabela de logradouro tenho: id, id_usuario, endereco, numero.

Como faço pra inserir/dar update em ambas tabelas de forma correta?

Como deve ser criado o model do Usuario e do Logradouro? Juntos, separados? O mapeamento da tabela (UsuarioTable, LogradouroTable) juntos, separados?

Como ficaria a questão dos Forms? Organização de pastas?

Comment: Se será utilizado duas entidades ou somente uma depende da regra de negócio da sua aplicação Felipe. São realmente necessárias duas tabelas? Um usuário pode ter mais de um endereço? Se sim é preciso de dois models, senão não precisa normalizar e o usuário pode conter todos atributos (endereço e número)

Comment: @gmsantos, seria mais para organização das tabelas, e eu também vou utilizar uma terceira tabela para pesquisar dados sobre logradouro de vários usuários, então penso que seria mais facil puxar desta forma o select. Porque na verdade, o cenário é que eu tenho tabela de cidades, estados, logradouro e a do usuario propriamente dita. A tabela de cidades tem o codigo do estado, a logradouro tem a codigo da cidade e o usuario tem o codigo do logradouro. Queria apenas entender como funcionaria esta questão de inserir em multiplas tabelas... Você pode me ajudar?

Comment: Felipe, sua dúvida é bastante específica da forma que está. Se a dúvida é inserir em mais de uma tabela basta criar dois inserts. Agora te ajudar com a implementação completa foge do escopo do stack overflow. Recomendo que leia o [tour] e também [ask].

Comment: Tudo bem, muito obrigado... Mas você poderia me dar um exemplo de como eu faria isto? Se precisar, posso colocar a estrutura do meu projeto, o que tem em cada arquivo...

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o model e o form de usuario receber tanto os dados de usuario como os dados do logradouro.

E salvar os valores nas suas respectivas tabelas, com isso você vai usar apenas um form e um model para realizar a persistência dos dados de um usuario, que apesar de serem tabelas diferente os valores são apenas de um usuario (logo não vejo logica em haver um model e um form para usuario e outro para logradouro).

No model de usuario você poderia fazer a persistência da seguinte forma.

```
    #Array com dados do usuario
    $usuario = array(
        'id' => $user->id,
        'nome'  => $user->nome,
        'email' => $user->email,
        'senha' => $user->senha,
    ); 

$this->tableGateway->insert($usuario); #inseri os dados na tabela usuario

$ultimo_usuario = $this->tableGateway->lastInsertValue; #recupera o id do insert

#prepara o TableGateway da tabela de logradouro
$adapter=$this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
$logradouro = new TableGateway('logradouro', $adapter); 

#Array com os dados do logradouro
$dados_logradouro = array(
        'id' => $user->logradouro_id,
        'id_usuario'  => $ultimo_usuario,
        'endereco'  => $user->endereco,
        'numero'  => $user->numero,
        );

$logradouro->insert($dados_logradouro); #Inseri o logradouro do usuario
```